# Nav Bar invisible when keyboard is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, navbar

I'm using the bellow code to move the screen up or down when the `textView` shows or hides the keyboard, by this way I can see the last field when it's focused.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField
{
    [self animateTextView: textField up: YES];
}


- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textField
{
    [self animateTextView: textField up: NO];
}

- (void) animateTextView: (UITextView*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 130; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.2f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But the problem is that the `navBar` it's also moved when the screen moves up, is there a way to move all except `navBar` or keep the `navBar` at it's position after using `[self animateTextView: textField up: YES];`?

Comment: Why? Why would you design your view like this? Why not use a `UINavigationController`? Why are you using `beginAnimations:` API? What is this, iOS / iphoneos 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have your custom NavigationBar in your main View.
Make another UIView below NavBar in your storyboard and then put your textField and other UI objects in this new View.
Keep this this is mind navBar should not be in side the same UIView object which you are pushing upward when the keyboard is appear.
So make an outlet of this newly create UIView object and instead for moving main view of the viewController just mode the newly created view like this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    //Just Replace Your Animation Code with This and see the difference.
    self.containerViewOfOtherObjects.frame = CGRectOffset(self.containerViewOfOtherObjects.frame, 0, movement);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you Syed, I have added, do I need to just replace the line `self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);` by the posted in the answer? Or also remove `[UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];`...

Comment: No. just this line. 
`self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);`

Comment: I have tried but it's like moving up and moving down really quickly the new added view to it's original place

Comment: let me add something.

Comment: Replace my code with these line of codes for smooth animations
`[UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];`